# Выборка первого коментария юзера

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица юзеров, и таблица комментариев.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE comments (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  CONSTRAINT fk_users_comment FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
)
```

Как выбрать юзеров, у которых created_at первого комментария попадает в заданный диапазон?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что "первый комментарий" - это комментарий с наименьшими датой-временем создания, то

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MIN(created_at) BETWEEN @start AND @end
```